# Powershell string separation

Tags: string, powershell, split

I have a string that has a value for example 22_ABCD
Now I only need the ABCD in my parameter. What is the best method to do this in powershell ?

Do I need to use a Split() and then take $stringvalue = Split[1] ? Or is there a function in powershell that does this?

Comment: Will all strings have the same format (##_aaaa)?  Please provide a little more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Split` is one way to do what you want and can be used like this... where the value between the brackets is the character that you want to use for the split.

```
$string = "22_ABCD"
$string.Split("_")
```

Running the above code outputs an array containing two items:

```
22
ABCD
```

You can then reference the second item in the array with `[1]` (`[0]` being the first item) like this:

```
$string.Split("_")[1]
```

Which outputs just the second item:

```
ABCD
```

Comment: Great, didn't know you could split the string directly. Thats great :)

Answer (score 0):

Regex is a possibility if you are looking for alphanumeric characters rather than just the next set of characters after an underscore.

```
$x = '22_ABCD_FTG_3'
[regex]::match($x,'([A-Z)]+)').Groups[1].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#method 0, with split operator
$Elements="22_ABCD" -split "_"
$Elements[0]
$Elements[1]

#method 1, with split member 
$Elements="22_ABCD".Split('_')
$Elements[0]
$Elements[1]

#method 2, with split member and direct affectation
$Element1, $Element2="22_ABCD".Split('_')
$Element1
$Element2

#method 3, with ConvertFrom-String
$Elements="22_ABCD" | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter "_" -PropertyNames "Element1", "Element2"
$Elements.Element1
$Elements.Element2

#method 4, with ConvertFrom-Csv
$Elements="22_ABCD" | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "_" -Header "Element1", "Element2"
$Elements.Element1
$Elements.Element2

#method 5, with regex
$Elements=[regex]::split("22_ABCD", '_')
$Elements[0]
$Elements[1]
```